# Is it possible to send characters to the USART->DR register without the COM port terminal?

Tags: stm32, uart

STM32 UART

If you send characters via COM port terminal on STM32, then the characters are stored in the USART->DR register.

[image]

Is it possible to write something in the code so that without the COM port terminal to save a character in the USART-> DR register?

Do not send to the COM port through the USART->DR register, but store it in the USART->DR register.

Comment: Maybe, but for what purpose? It may need to disable the UART or turn off the peripheral clock, but it would really help why do you want to write to DR register if you don't intend to send data out. Or is your goal to simulate a received byte and read it from DR?

Comment: Unless hardware handshake is enabled, the uart doesn’t know and doesn’t care if anything is connected. Also, don’t be fooled by what the debugger shows in the DR - it is reading it, so you won’t see the transmit value.

Comment: >Or is your goal to simulate a received byte and read it from DR?

Yes.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?  I cannot understand what you are asking.  First, do you understand how UART hardware works?  Second, have you looked at the UART block diagram in the STM32 manual?

Comment: Kartman in the message above described what I need.
--------------------------------
>Or is your goal to simulate a received byte and read it from DR?
--------------------------------
I need to simulate the reception of a character from a COM port on an STM32 (DR register).
This simulation must be written in code.
I know that the UART works differently, but I need this simulation for the test.

Answer (score 1):

No simulating of reading back what you wrote is not possible.

Just look at the block diagram of the USART.

Bytes written to DR go to transmit section to be transmitted out and bytes read from DR are read from receive section that have been received.

Comment: RXNE: Read data register not empty
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!This bit is set by hardware when the content of the RDR shift register has been transferred
to the USART_DR register.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

You described another case when there is a transfer from STM32 to COM port.
I need to simulate transmission from COM port to STM32.
And in this case, the characters are exactly stored in the USART_DR register.